# Как скопировать строку из одной таблицы в другую?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Есть 2 таблицы:

`busy_cars` (8 ячеек) и `cars` (7 ячеек). Мне нужно скопировать строку из `cars` в `busy_cars`, но добавив еще одно значение типа `int`

Пробую так, но очевидная ошибка: `7 values for 8 columns`.

`insert into busy_cars('id', 'name', 'age', 'city', 'desc', 'photo', 'price', 'client_id') SELECT * from cars where id=2`

Comment: `insert into busy_cars('id', 'name', 'age', 'city', 'desc', 'photo', 'price', 'client_id') SELECT *,еще_одно_значение from cars where id=2`

Comment: Возможно ли скопировать строку, заменив один столбец? Например, мне нужно, чтобы в новой строке были все значения из предыдущей строки за исключением одного первого столбца (id). Поскольку это forein key и не может повторяться, а формируется он генератором.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот это поможет вам:

```
INSERT INTO busy_cars('id', 'name', 'age', 'city', 'desc', 'photo', 'price', 'client_id') SELECT cars.*, 10 AS your_column FROM cars WHERE id=2;
```

Вместо `10` в `SELECT` может быть любое другое значение, которое вы хотите вставить, вместо `your_column` название колонки, в которую вы хотите вставить это значение.

**НО**. Если вы копируете строки из одной таблицы в другую, то это не совсем здоровое решение. Задумайтесь над использованием `foreign key`

**UPD** Учтите что при `SELECT cars.*` значения вставятся в том порядке, в каком они в таблице `cars`. Для того чтобы предотвратить это перечислите все колонки вместо `SELECT *` в том порядке, который вы указали после `INSERT INTO`.

Comment: а почему после cars точка стоит?

Comment: @ClarkDevlin Это синтаксис sql. Когда вы пишите `cars.*` это значит что вы хотите выбрать все колонки из таблицы `cars`

Comment: и наверное AS your_column надо выкинуть из тех же соображений, что это не имеет никакого значения

Comment: @splash58 Я за то чтобы это было, повышает читабельность)

Comment: `"Если вы копируете строки из одной таблицы в другую, то это не совсем здоровое решение."` - очень важное замечание. Подобные логические ляпы в модели данных могут привести к плачевным последствиям в будущем.

Comment: Тогда хотя бы поставьте этот ёёколумн еще и последней в списке

Comment: @MaxU, я не готов с вами согласиться вот так сразу.  у меня лежит несколько таблиц с адресами участников прошлых лет, и я примерно таким же запросом, добавляя тему сообщения и еще несколько параметров,  копирую эти строки в список рассылки. Так что это иногда надо

Comment: @splash58 "Тогда хотя бы поставьте этот ёёколумн еще и последней в списке" не понял о чём вы =)

Comment: @Inventor у вас в списке на вставку нет колонки your_column. поэтому  я непонимаю, какую читабельность вы повышаете

Comment: @splash58, я не видел ваших данных, поэтому не берусь судить... Но в случае с машинами нет смысла копировать данные о той же машине в другую таблицу только для того, чтобы добавить/удалить один столбец. Для этого существуют реляционные связи.

Comment: @splash58 я имею ввиду читабельность в коде приложения, а не в моём ответе. Я написал `your_column` потому что не знаю какой колонки не хватает, в вопросе не указано

Comment: @splash58 Я понимаю что интерпретатору вообще нет никакой разницы есть там `AS` или нет. Но как говорится задача хорошего программиста писать код не для машины, а для человека. В больших sql запросах `AS column` помогает мне и другим понимать куда эта колонка попадает и что за значение в ней

Comment: ладно, пусть будет так :) просто я полагаю, что в данном случае приписывание имени колонки запутывает, потому что создает иллюзию того, что можно подставить любую из списка

Comment: @MaxU машины это пример, в общем то. Суть немного в другом, когда оформляется заказ, то из одной бд строка копируется в другую, а из 1ой удаляется, а потом все возвращается назад. Тут тоже нужны реляционные связи?

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, реляционные связи создаются внутри одной БД - если у вас данные разнесены по нескольким БД, тогда лучше так не делать. Хотя не совсем понятно зачем здесь несколько БД)

Comment: @MaxU не так выразиился, бд одна, в ней 3 таблицы.

Comment: @ClarkDevlin не нужно в таком случае копировать и удалять строки, это делается с помощью `foreign key`